# Excel- add sequential numbers to column but skip if duplicate data in matching column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

2 questions: I have approx. 200 locations with equipment listing at each site. I have gateway#, name, type, location name.  Most pieces of equipment are at unique locations; however, some of my locations listing are blanks or duplicate entries which I need the duplicates as that indicates more equipment.
 I want to sequentially add numbers in a new column to identify each site (1,2,3, etc); however, if I have 2 or more pieces of equipment with the same location name existing, I want to give each duplicate cell the same number as the others that match and continue on.(If I have 3 rows with same location name, I want the newly assigned number to be reflected in my new column).

2nd question is if the equipment location is blank, copy info from other cell and then match that name for duplicates, if not assign a new sequential number
I manually accomplished what I want; however, I'd like a formula to automatically match conditions.

[image]

Comment: sounds like a few nested ifs and vlookups will work.  But without test data it is hard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: first time posting. How can I add my excel sheet for reference?

Comment: Best method, limit the data only to the data needed, mock it up and put it as text in the post.  Highlight the text and hit Ctrl-k.  It will format it as code.  Next is to load a picture of the limited data onto a third party site then link to it from here.

Comment: Sorry I don't download files from the internet.  Maybe someone who is more daring will.

Comment: (Not able to embed image so have to link to it) attached above

Comment: So if there were two rows with "Avon" as a name, but blank locations, you would want them to have the same new Loc #?

Comment: So equipment #25 says Avon but blank location and #26 says Avon but blank location in that instance I would want "Avon" copied in Location column and my new location # would be the same number for example 17 for both rows

Answer (score 1):

On cell E2 enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(D2="",B2,D2),IF(D2="",$B$1:$E1,$D$1:$E1),IF(D2="",4,2),0),MAX($E$1:E1)+1)` and copy it down

[image]

Comment: I duplicated row 18 to show that you get the same number (16) for both Jackson entries, so duplicates on column `B` with blanks on `D` share the same number

Comment: This is a TERRIFIC formula. It's extremely elegant. I learned a lot from this. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexM thank you very much! you made my day :-)